# How to implement post web service call in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to implement post web service call in sencha touch.What is bet way to implement webservice call

Comment: What have you tried so far? Question has a very broad scope. Can you please narrow it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Ext.Ajax.request()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) and pass `method : 'post'` in the options object.

Comment: How to use store and implement the post web service

Comment: Check the [Ext.data.proxy.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-property-actionMethods) docs